# How to utilize entire side of screen to transfer to a secondary monitor of a lower resolution in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

TL;DR: Does anyone know of a way that I can utilize the entire boarders of my 4K display to move to the 1080p ones on the sides.

I have a three monitor setup in Windows 10. Left and right monitors are large 1080p displays and my center monitor is 4K. If you look at the display settings you can see that the side monitors are one forth of my central one, since it's based on resolution, the issue with this is that depending where you place them relative to the 4k monitor that is the only region in which the cursor will transfer. What I have right now is that my right screen is "attached" to my central screen via its bottom half and my left screen via it's top half because those are the regions of those screens I use the most, but not always. The issue with this is that if I try to access my right screen with my cursor from the top half of my central screen, or my left monitor from the bottom half of my central screen, it gets stuck. I have to move it down and to the right or up and to the left, this really screws up with work flow, and gets obnoxiously annoying.

I see no technical reason other than laziness that the relative position of the cursor to the resolution cannot be translated and transferred to the same relative spot on a different resolution. But honestly at this point I would be willing to settle for it just going to the very top or bottom of the other screen if I move it over "out of region".

Comment: I can't believe this is a problem that actually exists, what was Microsoft thinking when they designed that?!

Comment: Is there a problem with your enter key? People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: ^^ or Return key ;-)

Comment: No, there is not a problem with my enter key. Grammatically speaking, there is not much wrong with my post, perhaps the lack of an indent at the beginning of the paragraph (stack exchange doesn't allow for grammatically correct indentations of paragraphs). I don't see a reason why a professional would frown upon a properly formatted English paragraph, since we aren't children on a playground. I suppose I'll separate the TL:DR sentence at the top from the detailed explanation of what is happening, because I am asking for help and it would seem that is why the community wants?

Comment: As far as I know this is not (yet) possible in windows. It could be coded (maybe with a third party driver or application), but then you would also need to tell your computer how big the display physically is or it would need to use DPI and not just resolution.

Comment: We are not children in a playground, we are professionals giving our help freely. We are also not writing literature or designing for a published work, we are posting semi-informally on a website, and the rules of formatting are different, and they're more like guidelines anyway. Breaking your Wall O' Text (TM) into manageable chunks with judicious use of the carriage return is a courtesy we give each other and one of several tools useful for improving the legibility of our communication. It makes it easier for the readers to read and comprehend, and therefore, answer, which is what you want.

Comment: My response matched the tone that I felt is insulting. It is one thing to inform me of suggested stack exchange etiquette as a better way to interact with the community, that clearly don't seem immediately obvious to me, given my background. It is entirely another thing to insult me and treat me like a fool.